# AspNetUsers tables and related not migrated back on registration after deleted

Tags: asp.net, migration, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing an Asp.NET mvc application. I am using identity system for authentication. But I am having problems with it because I deleted the tables required.

1. I created an account using UI and it auto migrated required tables, AspNetUser, AspNetUserRoles and so on.
2. Then I deleted that tables for some reasons
3. Then I enable migrations and set this, AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; in Configuration
4. Then I create another account from UI again.

It throws this error

[image]

Actually, it should not throws this error because I set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true` in Configuration. I searched solutions online, most of that errors throw in changing name of AspNetUsers table. But my problem is it is not migrating required tables back. Why is not migrating the required tables back? What are the possible errors?

In my previous projects, it I set auto migration to true, I auto migrated the required tables back on registration.

Comment: delete migration folders and build the project , it should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I deleted the migration folder. Enable migration again. Set auto migration enabled to true. That worked.

Comment: Actually i forget to mention that, you have to do The whole migration process again.